# Calls an Item from Fragment in Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments

newbe here.

I have an  `Activity` named `Main_Planner` and a `Fragment`named `Main_Itinerary`. When i want to access an item `TextView1` from the `Main_Planner` to `Main_Itinerary`. I will just use this code:

`Main_Planner mp = (Main_Planner) getActivity();`

```
mp.TextView1 .......
...
```

But how can i access the `Main_Itinerary` items to `Main_Planner`.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this

```
Main_Itinerary myFragment = 
        (Main_Itinerary) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragementID); 


if(myFragment != null){
    String value = myFragment.getValue(); // if getValue() is a public method
```

If the value you want to access from your fragment is not a method but a variable use variable name instead with right type

**NOTE**

`getFragmentManager()` if not using support fragment

Change `R.id.fragmentID` as per your layout

Comment: By putting your code in the`activity` can i access now the `fragment` items like `textview` ?

Comment: You can but I wouldn't suggest it. Better to call fragment method and make the UI changes there only.